How to join columns from different tables and insert a calculated column in PowerBI / Power Query
I have 2 tables in Power BI: ITEMS and SUB_ITEMS.

ITEMS is a table of actions to be performed.

SUB_ITEMS is a table of sub actions to be performed, regarding to the main action.

ITEMS has 15 rows.

SUB_ITEMS has 70 rows.


Each action in SUB_ITEMS has a percentage of completion:

sub action 1) 100%
sub action 2) 0%
sub action 3) 0%
sub action 4) 20%
sub action 5) 20%

In this case, the total progress of the main action (ITEMS) should be 28%:

sub action 1) 100% of 20% = 20%
sub action 2) 0%   of 20% = 0%
sub action 3) 0%   of 20% = 0%
sub action 4) 20%  of 20% = 4%
sub action 5) 20%  of 20% = 4%
total progress) 20% + 0% + 0% + 4% + 4% = 28%

I created a calculated table that gives me the percentage for each action (eg. 20%).
The percentage for each sub action is already in the table SUB_ITEMS (eg. 100%, 0%, 0%, 20%, 20%).
I need to put the column ITEM_NUMER, from ITEMS, together with SUB_ITEM_NUMBER into a new table, in order to apply the percentage from ITEMS (eg. 20%) over each percentage from the SUB_ITEMS (eg. 100%, 0%, 0%, 20%, 20%).
I don't know how to apply this percentage, once that the measure created to bring the 20% percentage is not available in Power Query, only in Power BI.
I'd appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance.

Assuming your data looks like this in Powerquery

Then in the ITEMS table, add column .. custom column .. with formula
 = [Percent]*List.Sum(SUB_ITEMS[Percent])


thanks a lot for your help. you helped me somehow. I tried to use the List.Sum on Power BI but, it is not available. so, what I did was to create measures on the SUB_ITEMS table bringing the Total of SUB_ITEMS, % of ITEMS using the Total measure and finally, a measure bringing the Sum of % of SUB_ITEMS so I could apply the % of ITEMS on it (you helped me on this part).
I'm expert on Access database modeling. what is very simple to be done in Access, it's been a challenge to me to be done in Power BI/Power Query.

Glad this helped. Please next time specify if you need a powerbi or powerquery solution, provide clear sample input data, and desired sample output data

I still don't know if what I need has to be done on PowerQuery or PowerBI. sometimes I want to joint 2 columns from different tables in order to create a calculated column (eg. Table1.Price and Table2.Quantity, Price * Qtd = Cost). so, when I create a calculated column on PowerBI, it doesn't appear on PowerQuery. when I create a measure, it also doesn't appear on PowerQuery. sorry for the bad explanation. next time I'll be more clear.
